# Kaminari not displaying links on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I just finished the default example project from Rails which is a blog, I decided to do a pagination with Kaminari. I'm using Rails 4.2.5 and kaminari 0.16.3. and when I try to paginate the index page where posts are displayed kaminari paginates the posts but it doesnt show the pagination links.

This is my code:

ArticlesController:

```
def index
@articles = Article.all.page(params[:page]).per(1)
end
```

View

```
<% paginate @articles  %>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
#print each article
<% end %>
```

Also I generated the views directory with the command:
bundle install -g kaminari -e erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your view file

you need to use

```
<%= paginate @articles %>
```

instead of

```
<% paginate @articles %>
```

in order to actually display the results of the ruby code to the html.